# Pricing of data importation into Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for the price of data importation from Cloud Storage to Big Query (through "bq import").

There is no "update" statement in BigQuery, so I want to drop my table and recreate-it from scratch.

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing?hl=FR), importing data is free. Only storing or querying it is charged.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data

There is update statement in BigQuery now.

But the quota is low. So yes, we would drop table and recreate table sometimes, instead of using update.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

**Data Manipulation Language statements
The following limits apply to Data Manipulation Language (DML).**

Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table: 96

Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per project: 10,000

Maximum INSERT statements per day per table: 1,000